# having 3 dropdown lists that i want to make 2 of them depened on the selection of the first one

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dropdown

i am using PHP MYSQL and JAVASCRIP AJAX.

i have multiple  dropdown list that i want to make it dependent on each other using AJAX  where these dropdown list includes data retrieved from MYSQL database.

the user select from the **first** dropdown list and based on its selection the **second** and **third**  dropdown list display the related values.

what i have done until now is to make the second dropdown list depend on the first one.

i need now to make the second and third be depend on the first one.

tables

- site_info:

  - siteID
  - siteNAME
  - ownerID
  - companyID
- owner_info:

  - ownerID
  - ownerNAME
- company_info:

  - companyID
  - companyNAME

## code1:

```
<form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
    <table border="0" width="30%">
        <tr>
           <td>Site Name</td>
           <td>Owner Name</td>
           <td>Company Name</td>
           <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

             <?php


                 $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT siteNAME, ownerID  from site_info");
                  foreach($query_site_name as $row)
                  {
        //           $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                   echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
                  } 

             ?>

            <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
            </select></td>

            <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
            <option value="">Select Owner</option>        
            </select></td>

            <!--create  dropdown list Company names-->


            <td><select id="Company_name"  name ="Company_name">
             <option value="">Select Company</option>       


 <script type="text/javascript">

// make Dropdownlist depend on each other
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#site_name').change(function(){
         var ownerID = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ownerID:ownerID},
            datatype:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#owner_name').html(data);
            }

         });
       });

    });

</script>
```

where this AJAX script is used to work between the first and second dropdown list only

## dropdown_fetch_owner.php:

```
<?php
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php');
 global $wpdb;
$output = '';
$sql =$wpdb->get_results("select ownerID, ownerNAME from owner_info where ownerID = '".$_POST['ownerID']."' ORDER BY ownerNAME");
var_dump($sql);

$output= '<option value="">Select Owner</option>';
foreach($sql as $row){

//while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output.= "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID."'>".$row->ownerNAME."</option>";
}
echo $output;

?>
```

thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your ajax code and you need to write 2 ajax request which is little tough to explain in some words..Just take a look on it..I hope it will give a better http://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: where is the error ? this link that you posted i already tried and did not work for me i am using wordpress

Comment: I dont know wordpress..according to my knowledge in ajax,data sending syntax is wrong  `data:{ownerID:ownerID},`    just try by removing curly braces like `data:'ownerID='ownerID,`